# Android: Restarting with a fresh version of the app being developed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to Android so please be as explicit as possible.
I'm trying to create a new activity.
the problem is that when I run the emulator from eclipse, I get the old version of my app.  I guess it's still running.
Is there a way to force a fresh install/restart of my new app?
I've read about the life cycle, and this might be related to that... but not sure.

How can I keep testing my app while I'm developing, and get the most recent version of my code on the emulator?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the app from eclipse and the new version will get pushed to the emulator and force stop or replace the old version. Note that if there are any compile errors, it will not do it.   If you just launch the emulator from the avd manager, or just run the app from the emulator launcher it will only have the last version you pushed to the emulator.

You don't need to restart the emulator or anything.

Comment: If you have a phone, you will find that the development process will go much faster and efficiently if you develop on your phone.  You can find instructions here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: I try to run the app from eclipse and it seems like it kept running even though the emulator was restarted.  Sometimes it even doesn't update when I change the orientation of the phone(screen). Would it have to do with something else? I think I read in a book that for developing for android it's better to use java for 32bit, I do have the 64bit version... any ideas?

Comment: when the emu is running, and you bring up the debug perspective and look at the devices tab, highlight the emulator instance you are using and look at the logcat output. what does it say is happening when you try to run the app from eclipse?

Comment: The debug perspective doesn't say anything, this is the output from the console:
`Sudoku] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android2.3.3'
Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
Uploading Sudoku.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing Sudoku.apk...
Success!
Starting activity net.ericpena.sudoku.Sudoku on device emulator-5554
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=net.ep.sudoku/.Sudoku }`

Comment: I got it working, I had some extra quotes on one of the xml file... I wish the debugger had caught it....
Sometimes the emm times out before loading my app, but I guess I'll just have to deal with that... thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever do need to uninstall, you should be able to do this through the phone/emulator menus Settings->Applications->Manage Applications->[Application Name]

However, this is not normally necessary, as the latest version should be pushed on a successful IDE build (or ant install)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: I've tried by just running the error-free app and by uninstalling the app, no success yet. Any ideas?